# Euler Characteristic of embedding regular subdomains

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry

For context, I am studying Beardon's book "Iteration of Rational Functions" and I am looking at defining the Euler Characteristic of a Fatou component by looking at the limit of convergence of the Euler characteristic of its regular subdomains that exhaust it. (Details are in Section 5.5)

We define a regular subdomain the following way:

[image]

The following lemma I am working on is here:

[image]

The issue I am having the text I've highlighted in red. It's probably something obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe an annulus is a regular subdomain.